# Resetting Score on Restart

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've got a small 2D game I'm creating with a score counter. On restart/game over I want the score counter to go back to 0 but I'm not sure how to go about that. This is for a game on Unity and I also call the counter on the player. I've attached my code down below and would appreciate any help!

```
public class CounterScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int scoreValue = 0;
    Text score;

    void Start()
    {
        score = GetComponent<Text>();
        scoreValue = 0;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        score.text = "" + scoreValue;
    }
}
```

Code on my restart button:

```
public class RestartButtonL1 : MonoBehaviour
{
    public CounterScript counter;

    public void restartScene()
    {
        counter.scoreValue = 0;
        SceneManager.LoadScene("GameSceneA");
    }
}
```

Code on my player:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Controller : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed;

    private Rigidbody2D rb2d;

    public GameObject restartPanel;

    private CounterScript counter;

    private void Start()
    {
        counter = GetComponent<CounterScript>();

        restartPanel.SetActive(false);

        rb2d = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    // ...    

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("PickUp"))
        {
            SoundManagerScript.PlaySound("sound");

            other.gameObject.SetActive(false);

            CounterScript.scoreValue += 1;
        }

        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Enemy"))
        {
            restartPanel.SetActive(true);
        }
    }
```

Comment: depends how exactly you restart your game? .. you could add `scoreValue = 0;` to the `Start` method (But if you have e.g. `DontDestroyOnLoad` this wouldn't get called) or the method which you use to restart. Is there a special reason why `scoreValue` is `static`?

Comment: literally just followed a tutorial so I've got no idea why things work like they do. I'll add in my restart button code!

Answer (score 2):

By making `scoreValue` a `static` value it is not affected by loading another (or the same) scene.

A quick fix would be to simply reset it befor loading the scene

```
public void restartScene()
{
    CounterScript.scoreValue = 0;
    SceneManager.LoadScene("GameSceneA");
}
```

or (I don't know how the tutorial works but if there is no `DontDestroyOnLoad` in play) simply always set the value in `Start` of the `CounterScript` (this works ofcourse only if there is no further switching scenes and other `CounterScript` instances)

```
void Start()
{
    score = GetComponent<Text> ();
    scoreValue = 0;
}
```

---

In this case it might be ok but in general you should try to avoid making stuff `static` just to access it "more easily" ... instead you should have

```
public int scoreValue;
```

and than have a reference to the actual instance of `CounterScript` like e.g.

```
public class RestartButtonL1 : MonoBehaviour
{
    // reference the CounterScript here by drag and drop
    // the acording GameObject from the scene into this field
    public CounterScript counter;

    public void restartScene()
    {
        counter.scorevalue = 0;
        SceneManager.LoadScene("GameSceneA");
    }
}
```

This is just an example how to access the instanced value e.g. whereever you increase it. Because actually by making it non-static it will be reset by (re)loading the scene anyway ;)

see also [Controlling GameObjects using components](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ControllingGameObjectsComponents.html)

*Sidenote: You always should remove empty `Start`, `Update` and other MonoBehaviour event calls. If you don't Unity calls them anyway causing some unnecessary overhead.*

Comment: in my player code I have "CounterScript.scoreValue += 1;" and it says "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'CounterScript.scoreValue'" would that have to do becaue I removed the static property?

Comment: yes and I just explained in the bottom how to still acess the value e.g. have a `public CounterScript counter;` in your player script, reference the according object and use `counter.scorevalue += 1;`

Comment: okay i called it "public CounterScript counter;" in my player script before the void start () part but it's still giving me the same error

Comment: did you reference it via the inspector? please checkout the link I provided

Comment: i tried: void Start()
    {
        int scoreValue = GetComponent<int>();
    }

Comment: nope! `int` is no component type ... you only can use it on the component like `GetComponent<CounterScript>();`. Also note that you don't want to declare the variable in `Start` as local value but rather want to fill a global value: `private CounterScript counter;    private void Start(){ counter = GetComponent<Counterscript>(); }` (get component only does the job here if the `CounterScript`) is attached to the **same** GameObject.)

Comment: it's still giving me the same error, I'll put some updated code in the post. Thank you for helping me out! Very frustrated since i need to fix the error before i can play the game

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191575/discussion-between-bubblegum-and-derhugo).

Comment: you fixed the GetComponent but you didn't fix the line where you change the value: `counter.scoreValue += 1;`

Comment: hmm but i need the scoreValue bit over in the counter script to increase it on screen?

Comment: What do you mean? By calling `counter.scoreValue += 1;` what you do is increase the `scoreValue` value of that instance of `CounterScript` so it will have a higher `scoreValue` the next time its `Update` method is called.

Comment: what would i need to fix to make it work though? It was working when the class was static but i guess i didn't realize the implications of doing that

Comment: I told you in this case you could even leave it static if it works for you .. I just said I would recommend to not to. What is not using when you do `counter.scoreValue += 1;`?

Comment: ahh i just changed it back to static since this is urgent. Thank you for your time, really really do appreciate it! I've actually learnt more in this chat than in class

Comment: No problem ;) Just make sure to get into some Unity and c# basics. There are a lot of good tutorials e.g. [Unity's own](https://unity3d.com/de/learn/tutorials)